# How to add animation when page change each other?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am looking for way to make slowly changing of pages after I press button. I want to use only JS without jQuery. Now I have script which change blocks, but I use display none; I am not sure that I can add slowly changing of pages with this. I tryied to use tramsform property but doesn't work good. I need dont have any overflow. It has to look close to this https://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow");

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function showNext(){
   
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    var nextToOpen = parent.nextElementSibling;
   
    nextToOpen.style.display ="block";  
    parent.style.display ="none";
    
}
}
```

```css
.big{
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: initial;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.one{
    background:pink;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    
}
.two{
    background:green;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display:none;
    

}
.icon-arrow-down2{
    font-size: 60px;
    color: silver;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.btn-arrow{   
    background-color : rgb(255, 238, 192);
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
.btn-arrow:hover{      
    border: none;
}
button, 
button:active, 
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="big">
        <div class="one">
            <button class="btn-arrow" onclick="showNext()">
                <span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to play with css animations. I have added some modifications to point you in the right direction. But basically, my recommendation is:

- All your pages have the same class with common styles (`.page`), and then each of them have different background-color.
- You need a specific class (`.page-visible`) that will be added to the next page you want to display, and removed from current visible page. This class just controls visibility. Please notice that the previous class (`.page`) has `display: none;`, as is the common one for all the pages.
- You will need a different animation for each movement (move up, move down, from left to right, from right to left). I just added one as an example in the code snippet.
- And then the magic comes listening to the `animationend` event: you apply the animation to both pages (the current visible and the next page), make next page visible applying the `.page-visible` class, and listen to endanimation event. When it happens, just hide the prev page removing `.page-visible` class, and remove animation classes.

The code works for just this 2 pages (one and two), but you can easily optimize it. I recommend you to take a look at [the original page you posted](https://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/), check their css and their js (open chrome developer tools and go to Sources, they don't have the files minified so you will see how they do everything :).

Does this make sense to you? I hope it helps and point you in the right direction. Animations are super fun! :)

(EDIT: Ah! I added some width&height to the button to be able to see it, hehe, it's up in the left corner now).

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-arrow");

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function showNext(){
      var visibleElement = document.getElementsByClassName('page-visible')[0];
      var nextToOpen = visibleElement.nextElementSibling;
      
      nextToOpen.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
        visibleElement.classList.remove('page-visible');
        visibleElement.classList.remove('page-moveUp');
        nextToOpen.classList.remove('page-moveUp');
      });
      visibleElement.classList.add('page-moveUp');
      nextToOpen.classList.add('page-visible');
      nextToOpen.classList.add('page-moveUp');
    }
}
```

```css
.page{
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}
.page-moveUp {
  animation: moveUp .6s ease both;
}
@keyframes moveUp {
  from { }
  to { transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

.page-visible {
  display: block;
}
.one {
  background:pink;
}
.two {
  background:green;
}
.icon-arrow-down2{
  font-size: 60px;
  color: silver;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.btn-arrow{   
  background-color : rgb(255, 238, 192);
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}
.btn-arrow:hover{      
  border: none;
}
button, 
button:active, 
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <button class="btn-arrow">
      <span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="page page-visible one"></div>
  <div class="page two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you you answer is really good. Cose works. And I undestood direction where I should move.